# How to Put Spacing Between these Options Using CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, whitespace, spacing

I've made a React App about pricing a spider drink and I would like to add spacing between these options (such as Name, Price, Quantity, etc. See picture below for clarification.) using CSS.

Is there a way to do this?

Picture of my React App:

[image]

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Here's my code in my add-ingredient.css and add-ingredient.jsx file:

```css
.style-up {
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
import React from 'react'
import './add-ingredient.css'

const AddIngredient = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <form className="style-up">
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="ingredient-name">Name</label>
                    <input 
                        type="text" 
                        required
                        minLength="3"
                        id="ingredient-name"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="ingredient-price">Price</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        min="0.01"
                        id="ingredient-price"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="ingredient-quantity">Quantity</label>
                    <input 
                        type="number" 
                        min="0.01"
                        id="ingredient-quantity"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="ingredient-measure">Measure</label>
                    <select id="ingredient-measure">
                        <option value="unit" selected>Unit</option>
                        <option value="Litres">Litres</option>
                        <option value="grams">Grams</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="ingredient-currency">Currency</label>
                    <select id="ingredient-currency">
                        <option value="$" selected>$</option>
                        <option value="£">£</option>
                        <option value="RON">RON</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">Add ingredient!</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AddIngredient;
```

Comment: We need to see the code to help you.

Comment: Okay, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This will solve your issue:*

I have just added:

```
form > div{
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

*for spacing between the options.*

```
label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

for spacing between `label` and `input`

You can tweak the values of both styles as per your requirements.

```css
.style-up {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

form > div {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

label {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
import React from 'react' import './add-ingredient.css' const AddIngredient = () => { return(
<div>
  <form className="style-up">
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="ingredient-name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" required minLength="3" id="ingredient-name" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="ingredient-price">Price</label>
      <input type="number" min="0.01" id="ingredient-price" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="ingredient-quantity">Quantity</label>
      <input type="number" min="0.01" id="ingredient-quantity" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="ingredient-measure">Measure</label>
      <select id="ingredient-measure">
        <option value="unit" selected>Unit</option>
        <option value="Litres">Litres</option>
        <option value="grams">Grams</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="ingredient-currency">Currency</label>
      <select id="ingredient-currency">
        <option value="$" selected>$</option>
        <option value="£">£</option>
        <option value="RON">RON</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Add ingredient!</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
) } export default AddIngredient;
```

I hope this was helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use margin to give spacing between them:

```
label { margin-right: 10px; }
```

Comment: Thank you, @BhojendraNepal, this also worked, too. 

Answer (score 0):

Add margin betweeen the input elements

```
.style-up  div{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for another solution, @karthik! 

Answer (score 0):

You can select the elements by their "id" or "class" and then give them a margin in CSS

`.element {
    margin: 5px 2px; 
}`

(the 5px sets the top and bottom margin)
(the 2px sets the left and right margin)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful solution, @RealMJDev. 